# MongoDb Compass: Not able to connect using standard connection string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have a mongodb hosted on an EC2 instance. The securirty group allows port 27017 and in mongo.conf, the port binding is set to `0.0.0.0`. I am able to connect to this mongo instance using the mongo CLI on my machine, so it means the server is accessable and port/ip binding is not the problem. But, I can connect using my MongoDb Compass application. It gives me this error:

> Authentication failed.

This is what my connection string looks like:

`mongodb://myuser:mypwd@my-ec2-ip:27017/myDatabase`

This is the same connection string I use to connect via the mongo CLI on my machine:

`mongo "mongodb://myuser:mypwd@my-ec2-ip:27017/myDatabase"` and this works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do username and password correctly escape all characters that must be escaped ?

Comment: Also, read the server log for clue as to why auth failed.

Comment: Most likely because your password contains special characters.

Comment: @D.SM Yes, the password just contains a-z and some digts.

Comment: In that case consult the server log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out compass was not picking up the authentication database from my connection string: `mongodb://myuser:mypwd@my-ec2-ip:27017/myDatabase`. `myDatabase` was the database I was trying to connect to buy compass was trying to authenticate me against the default `admin` database. So in the "Fill in connection fields individually" section, I set the "Authentication Database" to `myDatabse` manually and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Mongodb compass by default taking admin as database. So if you want to connect other database than admin then you have to use mongodb compass connecting string like:

```
mongodb://myuser:mypwd@my-ec2-ip:27017/?authSource=myDatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Security -> Database Access, change the **Database User Privileges** to **Read and write to any database**